# Solution check of differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Are these steps correct? If not what step is wrong?

1. $$
   \frac{dt}{dZ} = \frac{N}{P}\left (\frac{1}{Z} + \frac{1}{P-Z} \right )
   $$
2. $$
   \frac{dZ}{dt} = \frac{1}{\frac{N}{P}\left (\frac{1}{Z} + \frac{1}{P-Z} \right )}
   $$
3. $$
   \frac{dZ}{dt} \left( \frac{1}{Z} + \frac{1}{P-Z} \right ) = \frac{P}{N}
   $$
4. $$
    \left( \frac{1}{Z} + \frac{1}{P-Z} \right ) dZ \frac{1}{dt}= \frac{P}{N}
   $$
5. $$
    \left( \frac{1}{Z} + \frac{1}{P-Z} \right ) dZ = \frac{P}{N}dt
   $$
6. $$
    \int \left( \frac{1}{Z} + \frac{1}{P-Z} \right ) dZ = \int \frac{P}{N}dt
   $$
7. $$
   ln(|Z|) - ln (| Z-P|)= \frac{P}{N}t + C
   $$
8. $$
   ln \left(  \left |\frac{Z}{Z-P}  \right | \right) = \frac{P}{N}t + C
   $$
9. $$
   e^{\frac{P}{N}t + C} = \frac{Z}{Z-P}
   $$

Comment: yeah it looks correct to me.

Comment: Some might take reservation with the informality of the lines 4 and 5 and go directly from 3 to 6 citing the chain rule/substitution rule.

Comment: Why not just integrate with respect to Z in line 1 then skip lines 2 to 6?

Comment: looks correct to me too

Answer (score 0):

Every step is right

The only "mistake" that I found is in row 9.

from 9: we apply the exponent rules

$$e^{\left[\left(\frac{P}{N}\right)t\ +C\ \right]}=e^{\left(\frac{P}{N}\right)t}e^C=Ce^{\left(\frac{P}{N}\right)t}$$

Then: $$\mathbf{Ce^{\left(\frac{P}{N}\right)t}=\frac{Z}{Z-P}\qquad} or\mathbf{\qquad CZ=(Z-P)e^{\left(\frac{P}{N}\right)t}}$$